# How to get data from Backend in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to get data from my backend.

My backend exposes some data at http://localhost:8000/packs (I can see the data when calling this URL in my browser).

I want to get it into my frontend. To do so, I have created a service just like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UsuariosService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get_packs(){
      console.log("realizando consulta...")
      return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/packs");
  }
}
```

Then, In my component .ts, I do:

```
  getPacks():void  {
    this.usuarioService.get_packs().subscribe(
      res => {
        alert("Entrando en los paquetes")
      },
      err => {
        throw err;
      }
    );
  }
```

However, when I try it, I don´t get the alert that I have put there. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Where are we calling your `get_packs()` method? try `this.http
        .get("http://localhost:8000/packs")
        .subscribe(res => {
            alert("Packs obtenidos")
            console.log(res);
            resolve(res);
          },
          (err: any) => {
            reject(err);
          }
        )` in constructor.

Comment: That´s exactly what I already have. I guess you are talking about paquetes.get_packs(), which is a function that get create the conection and then it gets the data and return it.

Comment: From the code you posted, the function `get_packs()` is never called

Comment: convert observable to promise by  ` return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/packs").toPromise()`

Comment: Check this: https://therichpost.com/angular-9-services-working-example-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Use Angular's injectable services to wrap up your http requests.

Answer (score 0):

`http.get` returns an Observable. You can get rid of the promise part and write it as:

```
get_packs(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/packs");
  }
```

and then call get_packs as:

```
        this.usuariosService.get_packs().subscribe((res) => {
                alert('your text'); 
            }, (err) => { 
                //handle error 
            }
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a6k6ee?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I don´t understand where to put the call for get_packs that you are suggesting.

Comment: Normally you'll have a component that needs the data. So you'd inject the service there and then do the above call in the ngOnInit().

Comment: Yeah, now I see it. However, that calling gives me errors. Is it properly done?

Comment: Edited so the comment doesn't include the last bracket. Besides that it should be a valid one. What error are you getting?

Comment: async getPacks(): Promise<void>{
    this.usuarioService.get_packs().subscribe((res) => {
      alert('your text');
    }, (err) => {
    })
   }
  }

Comment: This way it is ok, however when I try is, it doesn´t work neither.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a6k6ee?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Example of how this should work.
I'd also recommend reading up on https://angular.io/guide/http to get a better understanding of it

Comment: I have changed my code so it looks just like the one in the example, but still not working. I don´t have any idea why it is not doing it!

Comment: It is not an error. It is just when I call the function, It doesn´t work at all. I have put an alert to check if it is working, but nothing. Check the edited code to check the current status of it.

Comment: Try changing the endpoint you call to the one in the example. If it works it means it's an issue with your API otherwise it's an issue with the angular code

Comment: I have used the other URL but I don´t get the alert in .suscribe neither.

Comment: I see. I can't help further without being able to see the code. If you can put your code in a stackblitz and share it then I can have a look.

Comment: For clarification, my server.js (which actually works when I enter localhost:8000/packs in the browser) is this: app.get('/packs',async (req, res) => {
    let result = await get_data();
    res.send(result);
    return res;
})

async function get_data(){
    let result = await paquetes.get_packs();
    return result;
}

Comment: Sure, I will put it. Give me a second.